# How to get the image url from an ImageField in a Django model with a JsonResponse?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I have this Model in a Django app

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    say = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    photo =  models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True)
    
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "user": self.user.username,
            "say": self.say,
            "date": self.date.strftime("%a-%d-%b-%Y , %H:%M:%S %p"),
            "photo": self.photo
        }
```

and this function in the views.py

```
@login_required(login_url = 'login')#redirect when user is not logged in
def all_comments(request):
    all_comments = Comment.objects.order_by("-date").all()
    return JsonResponse([comment.serialize() for comment in all_comments], safe=False)
```

and finaly this part of code in my javascript file

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    fetch('/all_comments') 
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(all_comments => {
do somethings with the data...
```

and when i run this i'm getting the error:

*TypeError: Object of type ImageFieldFile is not JSON serializable*

If i remove the line

"photo": self.photo

from the serialize function inside the mode everything goes fine and im getting the data that i need. How can i retrieve images url, with the JsonResponse as well, in order to display it with the other data? Ihave tryied many things i found here and there but i cant find any solution.
Thanks so much in advance

Comment: have you tried `self.photo.url ` ?

Comment: yes i did and it returned an error

ValueError: The 'photo' attribute has no file associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `.url` after photo will give you the photo's URL as a string, add like so:

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    say = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    photo =  models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True)
    
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "user": self.user.username,
            "say": self.say,
            "date": self.date.strftime("%a-%d-%b-%Y , %H:%M:%S %p"),
            "photo": self.photo.url
        }
```

Comment: i did but it returned an error 
ValueError: The 'photo' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: @NikolasSkordelis you'll just need to add a check to see if a file exists, like: `"photo": self.photo.url if self.photo else None`

Comment: thanks so much! why  is the condition necessary? i mean shouldnt allow to pass the image url and return None if an image didnt exists?

Comment: Because photo is `None`, and `url` is not an attribute of a `None` value.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    say = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    photo =  models.ImageField(upload_to='myphotos',null = True, blank = True)
    
    def serialize(self):
        if self.photo:
            return {
            "user": self.user.username,
            "say": self.say,
            "date": self.date.strftime("%a-%d-%b-%Y , %H:%M:%S %p"),
            "photo": self.photo.url
        }
        return {
            "user": self.user.username,
            "say": self.say,
            "date": self.date.strftime("%a-%d-%b-%Y , %H:%M:%S %p")
        }
```

or

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    say = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    photo =  models.ImageField(upload_to='myphotos',null = True, blank = True)
    
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "user": self.user.username,
            "say": self.say,
            "date": self.date.strftime("%a-%d-%b-%Y , %H:%M:%S %p"),
            "photo": self.photo.url if self.photo else None
        }
```

Note is it important to add `upload_to` to the `FileField or ImageField`.do not forget to run migrations an migrate.

Comment: thanks so much! why  is the condition necessary? i mean shouldnt allow to pass the image url and return None if an image didnt exists?

Comment: Yes you can get the `.url` only if there is an image otherwise python will raise an error.